# Trouble getting bootstrap tooltips to work on Joomla 3.0 with Gantry 4 Framework

Tags: javascript, joomla, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, typeerror

I am trying to enable the bootstrap tooltips in Gantry 4.

The bootstrap javascript is loaded, as bootstrap.min.js as is jquery.

I added the following to the index.php file just before the closing body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
  });
</script>
```

I seem to have a conflict as I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(document).ready(function () {
  $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
})')
```

The text that is supposed to trigger the tooltip is:

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Depuis le 1er juin 2004, la durée légale de la vie séparée a été réduite de quatre à deux ans.">le cas d&rsquo;un mariage de longue durée</a>
```

Can someone please point out what I need to do to resolve this? Thanks.

Sorry, I forgot to add the link to the site and page where the tooltip is not functioning.

http://gobet.ergonomiq.net/divorce-séparation/divorce/26-requérir-seul-le-divorce-après-deux-ans-de-séparation#

Comment: What does your JS order look in your header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have MooTools active on the website, so the $ selector doesn't work like it would if jQuery were the primary $ selector agent. You'll need to convert the uses of $ where jQuery is expected to use jQuery instead.

Example:

```
$(selector here)
```

should be:

```
jQuery(selector here)
```

And everything else will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have only 1 jQuery library being loaded and that it is at the top of the list. If not, then your bootstrap.min.js file won't work.

If this is done and it's still not working, try adding the code like so:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument(); //remove is this line is already being used
$js = "$(document).ready(function(){
          $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
       });";
$document->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I only have 1 jQuery library loading. `<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`, followed by `<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and immediately thereafter `<script src="/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. The only thing in jquery-noconflict.js is `jQuery.noConflict();`. I tried your suggestion, and that resulted in the following error: **SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF**.

Comment: ahh yes, so there was, sorry about that

Comment: @Irfan still getting the `SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF` error. If I include `$document = JFactory::getDocument();` I then get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'`. I'd be happy to give access to the server in a private message.

Comment: @alisamii - If you would like to send the server details to our company e-mail address, then you're more than welcome. admin@joomjunk.co.uk

Comment: @Lodder I sent an email requesting you to send me your **id_rsa.pub** key so I can add it to the server

Comment: @Lodder Did you get my email?

Comment: @alisamii - I don't seem to have received your e=mail

Comment: @Lodder, then please email me on ali.samii@ergonomiq.net and I will reply back. If you include your id_rsa.pub I'll put all the server info in my reply.

Comment: @lodder let me know when you have sent the email here, as I haven't received anything either, and that seems odd.

Comment: @Lodder Did you get a chance to send me an email so I could respond? I haven't received anything yet.

Comment: @alisamii - I didn't receive an e-mail from you unfortunately

Comment: @Lodder I realise that...That's why I asked thay you send me an email and I will reply to that. You can email me at ali.samii@ergonomiq.net. Please include your id_rsa.pub file in that email that **you** send me and in reply, I will send you all the login details.

Answer (score 0):

Add the bootstrap framework to the component.php of your template:
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
This should solve the ".tooltip is not a function" error

Answer (score 0):

1. In your Joomla Project, open `templates/<your-template-name>/index.php`.
2. find `JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true);` and comment it out.

OR You can just replace the word `behavior` with `bootstrap`.